# scalac :Out of memory during building Breeze

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scala-breeze

I'm trying to build [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) by myself using Intellij IDEA

Here's my enviroment
Intellij version:2018.2.1 Community
OS:Windows 10 64-bit
JDK version:1.8.0_181
scala SDK version:2.12
sbt version: sorry.. can't find it.

At First, It kept showing the error message : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

What I've done:
1. In "Custom VM Options", add "Xmx2048m"
2. In Settings(ctrl+alt+s)=>Build,Execution,DeployMent=>Build Tools=>sbt
change "Maximum heap size" to 9196 (really large...)
3. In Settings(ctrl+alt+s)=>Build,Execution,DeployMent=>Compiler=>Scala Compiler=>Additional compiler options, add "-J-Xmx4096m"
4. In Scala Compiler=>Scala Compile Server, change JVM maximum heap size to 4096

After doing these things, I still got a some chances to fail because out of memory during compiling.
Am I missing anything important?

Comment: For what it's worth, I frequently get OutOfMemoryErrors when building with Scala.

Comment: how do you solve it? Can you point out which setting is important? maximum heap size?

Comment: you should increase the maximum heap size as high as you can without thrashing. Hopefully several gigabytes (I usually find I need at least 4G for large builds). Still, even this may not be enough. In those situations, I resort to running incremental compilations multiple times. After the first one crashes, but manages to build a few files, the next one will use less memory. Not good for automated builds, but works for building while I work.

Comment: thanks, compiling many times seems to be a naive but useful solution, I was wondering why "Rebuild Module XXX" always failed and "Build Module XXX" can work sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using IntelliJ internal build system. Instead, try configuring IntelliJ to delegate building to sbt proper like so:

1. Enable [setting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#run_sbt_scala_app): `Use sbt shell for build and import (required sbt 0.13.5+)`
2. Create `.jvmopts` file at the root of your project:

   ```
   -Xmx4G 
   -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4G
   ```
3. In the `sbt projects` tool window, click `sbt tasks` node, and select the task you wish to run. Note, build commands from the main menu, for example,`Build | Build Project`, should now also be hooked into system SBT
4. Monitor the execution output in `sbt shell` tool window